# estimate pi using python

Tags: python, pi

my teacher gave this assignment asking to estimate pi at different values of "i".
i can get the first value of 4.0000 just fine but when i try for 101 i get 0.5024. Im honestly drawing a total blank here and the other questions on this site use a slightly different equation for estimation

here's my code:

```
num = 1

def m(i):  
    answer = 0  
    for k in range(num):   
        answer+=((-1)**(i+1)/(2*i-1))  
    return answer
```

and the question:

```
m(i) = 4*(1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9-1/11+⋯+〖(-1)〗^(i+1)/(2*i-1))
```

Your task: Write a function that returns m(i) for a given i and write a test program that displays the following table

```
i    m(i)
1    4.0000 
101  3.1515  
201  3.1466  
301  3.1449  
401  3.1441  
501  3.1436  
601  3.1433  
701  3.1430  
801  3.1428  
901  3.1427
```

any help is appreciated and please excuse my inability to format on here (i'm new)

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at your iteration:

```
for k in range(num):   
    answer+=((-1)**(i+1)/(2*i-1))
```

You're iterating over `k`, but `k` appears nowhere in the loop body. That can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jakob's answer, your for loop starts at k=0, to estimate pi you have to start at k=1.

I.e. change `for k in range(num):` to `for k in range(1,num + 1)`:

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce the correct result:

```
def m(num):  
    answer = 0          
    for i in range(num):
        answer+=(-1)**i*1/(2.0*i+1.0)       
    return answer  

for i in [1,101,201,301,401,501,601,701,801,901]:
    print i,"%.4f" % (4*m(i))
```